# The option to add an ADO.net data entity to my SL business application is not there. How can I find it?

Tags: c#, database, silverlight, ado.net

I've started my SL business application. When I created one previously, I also wanted to add an ADO.net data entity. This was all nice and easy; I clicked to 'add existing item' and in there was a multitude of options (including said ADO.net data entity).

Only this time there aren't these options. I've tried a navigation application and a business application and the only options I get in my 'installed templates' are under the heading 'Visual C#'. Within that there are sections for 'Code', 'Data', 'General', 'Web' and 'Silverlight'. While there are definitely Silverlight items to add, the list seems significantly smaller than before, and is missing a few things as I recall - including the ADO.net data entity. I have browsed them all, so I'm sure it's not there.

There are no other options on the left side for the selection of different templates.

Did I do something wrong? I didn't see many options when I created this application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at all a Silverlight expert, but since I'm interested in this topic I took a short look at it.

When you create a SL project, there are in fact two projects created: The client application and the host project, the latter representing the aspx application residing on the web server.

You cannot add ADO.net entities in the client application (and I do not know if you could before) but you can in the host project. A short google search gave me the following [result](http://www.codefest.at/post/2009/08/24/Silverlight-Entity-Data-Modelle-via-ADONET-Data-Services-in-Silverlight-konsumieren-e28093-Teil-1.aspx) (it's in german, sorry) which describes how to implement a web service on the server side which implements a RESTful interface to these entities. I'm not sure if direct data access from the client is (or ever was) allowed in Silverlight.

HTH

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I forgot that. Good thing I decided to go over it again. Thanks!

Comment: I found this discussion at http://forums.silverlight.net/t/95277.aspx/1 which says, that direct database access is not possible with silverlight. On the other hand the article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569758.aspx also suggests to implement an ADO.NET Data Service and provide access to the SL client using this service.